# retrieving private report metadata

Tags: metadata

using ant to retrieve metadata, it is easy to retrieve report metadata

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Some_Folder/Report1</members>
        <name>Report</name>
    </types>
    <version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```

and with "using scope allPrivate" we can use soql to query reports from private folders. However when I try to retrieve the metadata for these, it doesnt work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Private_Reports/Report2</members>
        <!-- is it something weird like this? -->
        <members>unfiled$private/Report2</members>
        <name>Report</name>
    </types>
    <version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```

What options are available?

Comment: Have you tried simply using `<members>*</members>`?

Comment: yes, but reports doesnt support wildcards https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it appears that this is only supported in SOQL, for purposes of cleaning up old reports/dashboards, which you can then delete via data loader/workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to retrieve the contents of users' personal report folders using the Metadata API. This has been documented as an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqhrAAC) for a whopping *eight years*.

Unfortunately, `USING SCOPE allPrivate` is [documented](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrZAAA0), as @sfdcfox noted, to be aimed at allowing administrators to delete private reports, and explicitly does not allow admins to view private folders.

The Analytics API is similarly limited and doesn't allow access to private reports. There's no way around asking users to move these reports to a shareable folder to access their metadata.